# Why do we always use phase lag instead of phase gain?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I saw in an online course I'm taking (edX » MIT » 18.03L) the equation:

> $$ \phi(\omega) = -\arg(G(\omega)) $$
>
> The **negative** of the arg, because we are talking about the phase **lag** rather than the phase **gain**.

That makes sense, but why is it such strong convention to use phase lag rather than phase gain?
Is it simply because there's no clear opposite of the word lag in English, or is there an intuitive reason to think of a system as introducing lag rather than the opposite?

Comment: The usual term is phase lead rather than phase gain, gain is usually associated with magnitude. This is speculation on my part, but physical systems tend to be low pass in nature and have phase lag characteristics, so possibly measuring lag made more sense historically?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a strong convention, it is simply a convention, the opposite one being equally valid to use. Note also that the opposite of the word lag in English in this context exists and is lead: phase lead. Possibly in your context you are used to study physically realizable dynamical systems which react to input with some lags and you want to use positive quantities when dealing with the "phase" of a system.